# Delimited List of strings in Excel, don't add delimiter if no value

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I would like to convert a list of values into a delimited string in Excel.
I looking for a NON VBA solution, but if you have a VBA solution please post so I can see how that is done.

I want to Turn

- Affiliate
- Hub
- DC
- Franchise
- HQ

Into: Affiliate > Hub > DC > Franchise > HQ

**Here is my current code**

This code works, but it is not elegant and difficult to expand out to more list items

```
=CONCATENATE(U3, IF(W3="","",LuKeyPathDelimiter), W3, IF(Y3="","",LuKeyPathDelimiter), Y3, IF(AA3="","",LuKeyPathDelimiter), AA3, IF(AC3="","",LuKeyPathDelimiter), AC3)
```

**Here are some screen shots**

- http://db.tt/k0RZdnVw
- http://db.tt/M0WXUABb
- https://www.dropbox.com/s/y1w42p7plhicsp9/shot_130130_091714.png

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the following VBA function instead of a worksheet function.  It allows you to concatenate a range of cells, with a delimiter you specify:

```
  Function Concat(useThis As Range, Optional delim As String) As String
     ' this function will concatenate a range of cells and return the result as a single string
     ' useful when you have a large range of cells that you need to concatenate
     ' source: http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/05/28/how-to-add-a-range-of-cells-in-excel-concat/

     Dim retVal As String, dlm As String, cell As Range
     retVal = ""

     If delim = Null Then
        dlm = ""
     Else
        dlm = delim
     End If

     For Each cell In useThis
        If CStr(cell.Value) <> "" And CStr(cell.Value) <> " " Then
           retVal = retVal & CStr(cell.Value) & dlm
        End If
     Next

     If dlm <> "" Then
        retVal = Left(retVal, Len(retVal) - Len(dlm))
     End If

     Concat = retVal

  End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version of the VBA solution, which has received good appraisal:

```
Function ConcatenateRange(ByVal cell_range As range, _
                    Optional ByVal seperator As String) As String

Dim cell As range
Dim newString As String
Dim cellArray As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

cellArray = cell_range.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(cellArray, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(cellArray, 2)
        If Len(cellArray(i, j)) <> 0 Then
            newString = newString & (seperator & cellArray(i, j))
        End If
    Next
Next

If Len(newString) <> 0 Then
    newString = Right$(newString, (Len(newString) - Len(seperator)))
End If

ConcatenateRange = newString

End Function
```

It's similar to the other answer but with some fundamental differences for speed and efficiency, such as using a variant array.